# Stacking several small divs or images next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add several divs next to each other and make them responsive like below. It should not be skewed but just several divs stacking next to eachother and still be responsive? How can obtain below? If it would be easier to make via. images? how can i stack these next to eachother and make them responsive?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by stacked? What do you mean by responsive? Please clarify your question.

Comment: .responsiveDivs{display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example: [jsBin responsive](http://jsbin.com/dilicu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

And here's the non-responsive

```css
body{ /* or a DIV parent */
  perspective: 1000px;
}

div{
  padding: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate3d(-20, -20, 15, -40deg);
}

div span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font: bold 2em/1.5 sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin:2px;
}
.W{background:#55CA55;}
.L{background:#D52A30;}
.D{background:#CCDC31;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class=W>W</span>
  <span class=W>W</span>
  <span class=L>L</span>
  <span class=W>W</span>
  <span class=L>L</span>
  <span class=W>W</span>
  <span class=D>D</span>
</div>
```